# Происхождение Бабы Яги

Tags: этимология, мифология

Собственно, я всегда знала, что слово "Яга" происходит от старого глагола "ягать", то есть, ругать, бранить. Но вчера смотрела передачу, в которой приводились другие версии. Мол, это означало мудрую, знающую женщину. Но, честно говоря, у меня возникло чувство, что это очередное измышление на тему идеализации нечисти.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто прав, и кто такая баба Яга на самом деле?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точное происхождение имени собственного не установлено. Есть масса версий, более или менее правдоподобных, но все - с негативными коннотациями, "мудрой" женщины среди них нет.

> > > Фасмер возводит имя Яга к праслав. *(j)egа, рефлексами которого являются сербохорв. jeзa «ужас», jeзив «опасный», словен. jezа «гнев», jeziti «сердить», др.-чеш. jeze «lamia», чеш. jezinka «лесная ведьма, злая баба», польск. jędzа «ведьма, баба-яга, злая баба», jędzić się «злиться» и т. п. Однако в русском языке есть когнат ко всем перечисленным примерам из славянских языков: язва. Что ставит под вопрос существование связи между именем Яга и приведенными примерами из славянских языков. Также возможна этимология, в рамках которой древнее заимствованное название было переосмыслено славянами и сближено с производными от праслав. *(j)egа (народная этимология), что объясняет флуктуацию, выраженную в наличии вариантов с -z- и -ž- в западно-славянских языках (имя переосмыслено) и наличии варианта с -г- в русском языке (не переосмыслено).

(Вики)

"Кто она такая".

Вообще вопросы об этимологии большинства представителей русского пантеона духов и фольклорных персонажей обычно спорны и не имеют однозначного ответа. Чтобы эту этимологию корректно вывести, надо не только представлять роль и сущность такого персонажа, надо еще и продраться сквозь частокол переосмыслений, представлений, фантазий и "народных" этимологий. А это работа специалиста. 
Я не берусь. Пересказывать чужие противоречивые истории про то, кто такая Яга, почему она Ивашку не съела и чем русский дух чувствовала - это, конечно, интересно... Но не в рамках вопроса об этимологии.

Я лично придерживаюсь простой формулировки, что это персонаж русских сказок, возникший из славянского злого духа. Женского полу, одинокая, вредная, живущая преимущественно в лесных избушках... Остальное - уже зависит от Вашей фантазии.