# Склонение слов «баба-яга» и «чудо-юдо» во множественном числе

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как склоняются во множественном числе «баба-яга» и «чудо-юдо»?

Comment: ничего себе вопросики с утра... Для начала здесь посмотрите https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/40533 по поводу имени, а ответ я дам попозже, если не опередят.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Орфоэпический словарь под ред.Аванесова дает такие формы. В единственном числе чудо-юдо, род падеж чуда-юда.
Множественное число чуда-юда,  род падеж мн числа неуп., чудам -юдам и т,д,

Баба-яга', бабы-яги', мн.число бабы-яги', род.падеж мн.числа не употребляется,бабам -ягам' и т.д.

Comment: Интересно... Пропустил я. Здесь я со всем готов согласиться, кроме ударения. Ну нет в русском языке такого, чтобы ударение в подбных словах и флексии на основу не переходило.

Comment: Вы же сами когда‐то рекомендовали именно этот словарь. Да и все его рекомендуют.

Comment: Так я не возражаю. Аванесов - вполне авторитетная словарная фиксация. Спасибо, что нашли. А я именно что пропустил. Это в отношении чуда-юда. А вот с бабой-ягой есть реальные сомнения в отношении ударения, да. Но это уже другой уровень обсуждения....

Comment: Кочерга, кочерги'

Comment: Это не двусложное слово, и вообще уникальный случай - там беглая гласная (кочерёг), на которую ударение, естественно, падать не может. Есть еще бразда-бразды, но это опять-таки казус, связанный с неполногласием. Я от вас не требую опровержения, я объясняю, почему сомнения.

Answer (score 2):

**Баба-яга**

Предлагается вариант
И. бабы-**я**ги,
Р. баб-**я**г,
Д. бабам-яг**а**м,
В. баб-**я**г,
Т. бабам-яг**а**м,
П. (о) бабах-яг**а**х.

Аналогично для имени собственного Баба-Яга.
Ключевые моменты: склонение обоих слов (по образцу имени собственного), одушевленное, смещение ударения на первый слог. На всё есть обоснования, не абсолютные, но весомые.

Во-первых, само написание. Какого бы ни было происхождение второй составляющей (а на это много всякой ерунды понаписано), исходно она представляла собой имя собственное - и писалась (или должно было писаться) "баба Яга". Это важно представлять для выбора форм склонения. Собственно, словари идут по тому же принципу, сохраняя даже в дефисном написании принцип раздельного склонения частей. Здесь прослеживается тот же принцип, что и с дедом-морозом, который сохраняет раздельное склонение даже в качестве имени нарицательного.

Этот же сравнение позволяет предположить, что склонение второй части идет по одушевленному принципу ("мороз" - одушевлен: вижу "деда-мороза", не "деда-мороз"). Видимо, это должно сохраниться и во множественном.

Несколько более сложным является обоснование единого правила для имен собственного и нарицательного. Нормативное дефисное Баба-Яга не имеет аналога у Деда Мороза, там персонаж пишется раздельно. Но все же, думается, этот принцип можно перенести и на имя с дефисным написанием.

Остается вопрос ударения во второй части.
Я его решаю исходя из общей модели переноса ударения во множественном числе у двусложных слов женского рода с ударным окончанием: вода-в**о**ды, трава-тр**а**вы, жена-ж**ё**ны. Бесспорных примеров иного я не знаю.

Повод для сомнения дают только случаи (не совсем естественные) образования множественного числа от имен собственных... Ну вот такой текст хотя бы: *"Есть деревня Воронья нога, деревня Курья Нога, деревня Связанные Ноги. Есть фамилия Нога. Все эти Н**о**ги/Ног**и** представляют весьма трудный случай для грамматики".* Шут его знает, где у этих "Ног" ударение. В фамилии  ударение вроде бы не должно смещаться.

Но доводов для его смещения все-таки больше.

Пожалуй, это все, что имеет отношение к делу. Хотел написать больше и подробнее, но что-то обстановка накалилась, нет настроения. Надеюсь, что ничего существенного не опустил.

//= = = **UPD**
V.V. указывает на Аванесова. У него ударение не смещается. 
При всем уважении к А. не могу просто так согласиться. Нет такой продуктивной модели в Р.Я. Т.е. нужно какое-то обоснование, помимо постулативного.

https://povto.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskie/avanesov/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0616.htm

//= = = **UPD-2**
уточнил Д. Т. и П. падежи. там-то ударение не смещается, это я поторопился в оформлении.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала о **чудо-юде**.

Предлагаю: **чудо-юды, чудо-юд, чудо-юдам** и т.д.

С этим словом и в единстивенном числе не все однозначно. Надо ли его склонять по образцу *фокус-покуса*, *шалтай-болтая* (нарицательное), *пинг-понга, гоголь-моголя* (только вторую часть) - или по образцу собственного *Шалтая-Болтая* (обе части)?

У меня нет никакой уверенности, что исходно это не имя собственное, хотя и пишется не с прописной. К тому же все приведенное - заимствования, слегка, правда, переделанные (Шалтай-Болтай в оригинале Хампти-Дампти). А чудо-юдо оно наше, родное. К тому же первая часть однозначно сохранила свое семантическое значение и в основном определяет значение всего составного слова.

Но приняв вариант склонения  обеих частей мы неизбежно сталкиваемся с неразрешимой задачей выбора форм множественного.

*Чуды-юды* или *чудеса-юды*? Или вообще *чудеса-юдеса*? 
Я бы из этих вариантов выбрал первый. Смотрится естественнее, но противоречит правилу склонения слова "чудо" (как небо-небеса). И эта новая головная боль.

Кроче, пока и если не будет словарной фиксации предлагаю избавиться от всех пробюлем и выбрать варинт нарицательного шалтай-болтая, пусть и с некоторым волюнтаризмом в принятии сего решения.
Родительный падеж множественного несвободен, но сомнений не вызывает.
Остается вопрос винительного множественного. С некоторыми сомнением предполагаю одушевленный тип. 
Итак:
И. **чудо-юды**,
Р. **чудо-юд**,
Д. **чудо-юдам**,
В. **чудо-юд**,
Т. **чудо-юдам**,
П. **(о) чудо-юдах**

(Про ягу/Ягу - много сложнее, дам отдельным ответом. Я разделяю ответы, поскольку это два в чем-то похожих, но существенно разных случая, оба предельно дискуссионны - и заслуживают отдельного обсуждения.)

//= = = **UPD**
V.V. указывает на Аванесова. Вынужден признать, что я ему противоречу, но я согласен с таким вариантом. 
https://povto.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskie/avanesov/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0616.htm

Comment: давайте. интересно.

Answer (score 0):

*Бабки-ёжки, чудища-юдидища.* В словаре синонимов Тришина есть *юдище* и *чудище-юдище* (ед.), но я бы упростил слово до "чуда-юдища" (со склонением только второй части).

Comment: а если не изменять слово?

Comment: Alex_ander, хотя бы пару фраз вначале о невозможности/ненужности склонения слов из вопроса.

Answer (score -2):

Склонения давно известны.

## Чудо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Чудо-юдо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Баба-Яга

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/Баба-Яга](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D0%AF%D0%B3%D0%B0)

Comment: Вас не смущает даже то, что в вашем "источнике" используется орфографически неверное написание?!

Comment: А вы докажите, что там неверно. До тех пор это ваше "неверное" мнение.

Comment: А зачем? Я просто дам свой ответ. А Вы даже ссылку не дали на тот ресурс, где это  "давно известно". Как можно что-то доказать автору, считающему подобное компбеютерное словотворчество аргументом? С меня хватит того, что вы не различаете склонения имени собственнного и нарицательного

Comment: @behemothus В Википедии тоже неправильно склоняют?! https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Чудо-юдо Докажите всему миру, что все не правы, а правы только вы.

Comment: Во-первых, не в википедии, а вики-словаре. Во-вторых, "всему миру" известно, что он нормирующим источником не является.

Comment: Стоп. Я вам дал ссылку на Википедию. А по поводу бабы-Яги (что из вики-словаря) у нас ответы совпадают.

Comment: Я у вас ничего не брал.

Comment: *А по поводу бабы-Яги (что из вики-словаря) у нас ответы совпадают.* -   а вот это уже не соответствует истине.

Comment: Повторно: ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Чудо-юдо || "Но совет такой: бабы-яги, баб-яг, бабам-ягам. Ударение обязано быть на Я." --- совпадает!, только в вики-словаре не указано фразовое ударение (которое, очевидно, на Я), а просто ударения отдельно по каждому слову. || Подскажите, а как можно умудриться напечатать такое слово "бьдщралз" человеку, который "хорошо" знает русский язык?!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98956/discussion-between-behemothus-and-oleedd).